# <img> element should responsively resize, relative to the width of its parent element, without exceeding its original size

Tags: css, responsive-design

I started working on tribute page project on codepen passed 9 test cases. Tried all the ways but cannot pass the last test case.

**My css code**

```css
#img-div {
  display: block;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 100%;
} 

#img {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: auto;
   padding-top: 10px;
   max-width: 100%; 
}
```

[Here is my project.](https://codepen.io/Pavithra-T/pen/JjWmYRE)

Comment: You're almost there :). You just forgot to use the proper selector. Right now you're using the `#img` selector, but the image had an id of `image`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the used CSS selectors which you should fix: To the given `width` in percent just add a `max-width` with a pixel value that equals the original width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the Bootstrap CSS Library from a previous freeCodeCamp lesson, which in this case requires you to add the link at the top of your HTML document:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

Once the Bootstrap link is there, you just add `class="img-responsive"` to your image element, the image resizes appropriately and passes the test.